# How can I edit commit messages in my wp-hosted plugin repo?

Tags: plugin-development, svn, version-control, plugin-repository

I stupidly committed code with a commit message that doesn't make sense. I looked up how to edit commit messages for SVN repos and read [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304383/how-do-i-edit-a-log-message-that-i-already-committed-in-subversion), however, unfortunately it seems like I need to "have admin rights (directly or indirectly) to the repository to do this."

I tried to follow the directions in the stackoverflow post, but got this message after attempting to edit my last commit message:

```
svn: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
svn: E175002: Error setting property log:
Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges;
ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```

So- it obviously seems like the folks managing the WP plugin repos don't give plugin devs admin access to their repositories, so what's the best way to go about editing commit messages? Is there anyway to do this? Am I left with no other choice but to add another commit message saying "ignore the last one" (eep) ?

Comment: I don't think anyone is particularly looking at those logs. If it was something sensitive (like a password for something :) I'd consider contacting WP org about possibly scrubbing it. Otherwise — not worth wasting time on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the best way to go about editing commit messages?

1. Don't worry about it, don't make such mistake in future
2. "ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook"